# Several indicator apps removed on 13.04 system tray

Tags: 13.04, indicator, system-tray

I recently upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 and I know that during the upgrade Ubuntu removed some of my indicator apps (weather app, Xpad, Artha dictionary, Banshee).

Can I still restore them on my system tray? How?

Answer (score 1):

Crossposted from another Ubuntu forum community, someone linked me to the steps on how get back the system tray whitelist.

From a [Web Up8 post](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html):

**Step 1:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:timekiller/unity-systrayfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Step 2:**

"Then, restart Unity by pressing ALT + F2 and entering "unity" or by logging out."

**Step 3:**

Dconf Editor > com > canonical > unity > panel > systray-whitelist

Additional reference: [HOW TO RE-ENABLE THE NOTIFICATION AREA (SYSTRAY) IN UBUNTU, FOR ALL APPLICATIONS](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most easy way is to install them again by using Ubuntu Software Center. Just look for them again and install them.